# Why does onBeforeFirstShow work?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have been learning the master-detail demo, below is a snippet in `Master.controller.js`

```
onInit : function() {
    this.getView().addEventDelegate({
        onBeforeFirstShow: function () {
            this.getOwnerComponent().oListSelector.setBoundMasterList(oList);
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

I can not understand that event delegate because I haven't seen `onBeforeFirstShow` event is in any control/view API doc.

Is this is a just user-defined event or a pre-defined event?

---

I have tried

```
this.getView().addEventDelegate({
    onBeforeFirstShow: function () {
        console.log("onBeforeFirstShow");
    }.bind(this),
    onAfterRendering: function () {
        console.log("onAfterRendering");
    }.bind(this)
});
```

It seems that it happens before `onAfterRendering`. Besides:

- `this.getView().onAfterRendering` returned `function`
- `this.getView().onBeforeFirstShow` returned `undefined`.

I have searched in doc of [Controller](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.html) and [View](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.View.html),  and source code of [sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller.js#L58) and [sap.ui.core.mvc.View](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/mvc/View.js#L73). There are only four lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event `beforeFirstShow` is available for the view because the view is a direct aggregation child of [`NavContainer`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainerChild.html). Other than that, there are currently also

- `afterHide`
- `afterShow`
- `beforeHide`
- `beforeShow`

Those events are triggered by [`sap.m.NavContainer`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html) on its child controls (in our case, the view) when navigation occurs and child controls are displayed/hidden.