# onBeforeShow of a Nested View Is Never Called

Tags: sapui5

I defined a handler for the [`beforeShow` event](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.NavContainerChild/events/BeforeShow) in `onInit` of the nested view:

```
this.getView().addEventDelegate({
    onBeforeShow: jQuery.proxy(function(oEvent) {
        this.onBeforeShow(oEvent);
    }, this)
});
```

and then:

```
onBeforeShow: function(){
    alert("Hello!");
}
```

But this handler is never called.

I need an event to be triggered in the controller of the nested view every time the nested view is displayed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Event handlers, such as `onBeforeShow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44882676/5846045), can only be called when the navigated control (in our case, the nested view) is a direct child of a NavContainer as described in the [API Reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.NavContainerChild):

> Events (are) triggered by [sap.m.NavContainer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.NavContainer) on its child controls when navigation occurs and child controls are displayed/hidden.

This means, you'll have to wrap the nested view in a NavContainer and make use of it (possibly in combination with Router) to hide and display the view so that `onBeforeShow` works.

Here is a working example: https://embed.plnkr.co/HRSJ44/. If you open the browser console, you'll see that `onBeforeShow` is called every time when the nested view is about to be displayed.